# Can gravitational waves have event horizons?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, gravitational-waves

Is there a spacetime that contains traveling planar event horizons?

Comment: The [Alcubierre metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) isn't planar, but it does have a type of horizon.  It may be of interest.  The standard plane-wave formalism when you're talking about gravitational waves is the [pp-wave spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pp-wave_spacetime), but I don't believe there's any form of them that would lead to a horizon.